# How to find which pairs of predictors are highly correlated in R ? Given are 3 predictors X1, X2, X3 and dependent variable is Y

Tags: r, linear-regression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCv2A.png)

Tried using vif() function but how to get the correlation between pairs of predictors?

fit<-lm(y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=data1)
vif(fit)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find correlations between varibles with the `cor` function and plot it with the package `corrplot`

```
library(corrplot)
df <-
  data.frame(
    x1 = round(runif(100, min = 100, max=170)),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
    x3 = round(runif(100), 2),
    y = round(runif(100), 2)
  )

cor(df)
corrplot::corrplot(cor(df),method = "color")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the correlation coefficients, you can just use `cor`. If you want them all in a go, use `sapply`:

```
sapply(data[, c("X1", "X2")], function(x) cor(x, data$X3))
```

Comment: This will only compute the correlations of columns 1 and 2 with column 3. Not that *cor* already returns the full correlation *matrix* when applied on a data frame, e.g. `cor(iris[,-5])`.

Comment: Right! I hadn't noticed the answer by @Elia, that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways..

Create dummy data

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    x1 = round(runif(100, min = 100, max=170)),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
    x3 = round(runif(100), 2),
    y = round(runif(100), 2)
  )
```

Using `psych` package

```
library(psych)
  pairs.panels(df, 
            method = "pearson", # correlation method
            hist.col = "#00AFBB",
            density = TRUE,  # show density plots
            ellipses = TRUE # show correlation ellipses
            )
```

Using GGally package

```
library(GGally)

    ##GGally package
        ## Correlation matirx
    
            ggcorr(df,
            nbreaks = 6,
            label = TRUE,
            label_size = 3,
            color = "grey50")
        ## Correlation Plots
            ggpairs(df, columns = 1: ncol(df), title = NULL,
                upper = list(continuous = "cor"),
                lower = list(continuous = "smooth"),
                mapping = NULL)
```